# Change color scheme of active/open files drop down in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, settings, color-scheme

Is there any way to change this? Either the background or the foreground color would help. Mine is pretty much unreadable at the moment.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the theme switcher extension?

Comment: @Mrchief I have the theme editor installed, is that what you mean?

Comment: That's what I thought. I would suggest exporting your current settings to a `vstheme` file and look for background color entries.

Answer (score 0):

With the Theme Editor extension installed, go to *Theme > Customize Colors*

Modify the values of *CommandBarMenuBackgroundGradientBegin* and *CommandBarMenuBackgroundGradientEnd* to change the background color.

The background color of the file icon can be changed with *CommandBarMenuIconBackground*.

Answer (score -1):

For Default look and feel of Visual Studio you can go and reset your Environment Settings !

Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings

But

You can use "Visual Studio Color Theme Editor" Extension. Click [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378)

or You can go to http://www.studiostyl.es/ and download any theme you like then install on your machine.

by the way this is very nice post from Scott 
Click [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx)

Comment: I already have color theme editor. It doesn't really help if you don't know what the menu is called. I tried changing the color of all dropdowns but that didn't affect it.